# Can't import zipline.transforms

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, zipline

I'm trying to import zipline.transforms, but the output message says No module named transforms. I'm using python2.7 and downloaded zipline via conda.

```
from zipline.transforms import batch_transforms

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-253f85965feb> in <module>()
----> 1 from zipline.transforms import batch_transform

ImportError: No module named transforms
```

Comment: Are `zipline` and `python` both 64/32 bit version?

Comment: I know python  is 64 bit, how can I check zipline bit?  Sorry I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: How did you install zipline? Can you please put the exact command?

Comment: ' conda install -c Quantopian zipline'    I just put this command in the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

First, is your IDE (pycharm or sublime) included Anaconda in the path?  Second, please check where you zipline module was installed, usually .../lib/python2.7/site-packages/zipline, does it include a module called "transforms"? maybe it's an old module, not in the updated zipline anymore.